# E11000 duplicate key error index - Grails afterInsert() method

Tags: mongodb, grails

I m getting this weird error and unable to find any solution with previous answers on this issue, I think therr is some other issue with my case.

I'm getting this issue in my `afterInsert()` method in domain like this

```
Class Employee {
    /** other code **/

    def afterInsert() {
        println "Inserting..."
        if (!hasAfterInsert) {
            hasAfterInsert = true
            DatabaseEvent.withTransaction { status ->
                def dbEvent = new DatabaseEvent(loggedInUser: null,
                        type: "Created", entityClass: this.getClass().getName(), eventObjectId: this.id)
                dbEvent.save(failOnError: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After inserting a new employee I am creating a record using this method, but this is throwing this error on when I have this code in `afterInsert()`.

My `DatabaseEvent` class is like

```
class DatabaseEvent {

    ObjectId id
    String type
    String entityClass
    String eventObjectId
    Date dateCreated
    User loggedInUser
}
```

This is giving something like:

```
E11000 duplicate key error index: myApp.Employee.$_id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5631313fe4b0bbeba418859b') }
```

I don't understand why is this happening when I m saving `DatabaseEvent` object in `afterInsert()`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when you are saving your new instance of `Employee`, your GORM session is not yet flushed that means your new `Employee` instance is still in the GORM session and your new `Employee` instance got a new `id` i.e. `ObjectId('5631313fe4b0bbeba418859b')`.

Now in your `afterInsert()` method, you are using the same transaction to save a new instance of `DatabaseEvent`. On saving the new instance of `DatabaseEvent`, GORM is flushing the same GORM session again and the recently created instance of `Employee` is again tried to save with the same `id` with value `ObjectId('5631313fe4b0bbeba418859b')` which is causing the duplicate key error.

So just change your code in `afterInsert()` method to use `withNewSession` instead of `withTransaction` closure and this should work.

Comment: any help on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412721/unable-to-get-dirtypropertynames-properties-values-for-association-fields-in-gra ..

Comment: Sure. Posted the answer there.