# Unable to get dirtyPropertyNames properties values for association fields in grails

Tags: mongodb, grails

I need to check the previous state of the object so to log the changes happened. I'm using `dirtyPropertyNames` to extract such properties,
but it is not giving me the persisted values of association fields, my code is given below

```
class Employee {
    String name
    String title
    String city
    List<Address> addresses
    List<Skill> skills

    static hasMany = [skills:Skill,addresses:Address]
    }

  static belongsTo = [Skill]
  static embedded = ['skills', 'addresses']
}
```

In my code in `beforeUpdate()` method, when I check the `dirtyProperties` it gives me the persistent values of `name, title, city` using the code below  :

```
def beforeUpdate(){
    this.dirtyPropertyNames?.collect { name ->
        def originalValue = this.getPersistentValue(name)
        def newValue = this."$name"
        println "$name : old:: $originalValue , new:: $newValue ."
    }
}
```

but the persisted values of skills and address in employee record are not shown at all, I'm using MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, GORM for MongoDB does not give correct values in the `dirtyPropertyNames` field. So you have to use another lower level injected field in the domain instance i.e. `$changedProperties`.

But, there is also a problem with the `$changedProperties` that even if the you bind a field with the same value, the `$changedProperties` will have an entry for it. So you can tweak it a little more like this to make your code work:

```
def beforeUpdate() {
    def instance = this
    Map updatedFields = instance.$changedProperties

    updatedFields.each { name, value ->
        if (updatedFields[name] != instance[name]) {
            println "Field value $name is updated"
            if (name == "addresses") {
                // I've not run this for a long time, just confirm the old and new addresses values and swap the assignment of below lines
                List newAddresses = updatedFields[name]
                List oldAddresses = instance[name]

                newAddresses.each { address ->
                    if (!address.id) {
                        println "Got new address: $address.status"
                    } else {
                        Address oldAddress = oldAddresses.find { it.id == address.id }
                        if (!oldAddress) { // This is just an edge condition
                            println "Got new address: $address.status"
                        } else if (oldAddress.status != address.staus) {
                            println "$address status is updated to $address.status"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this, but it not giving the object , instead it gives me something [app.Address : (unsaved)] , new:: [app.Address: (unsaved), app.Address : (unsaved)]

Comment: value for addresses field is embedded is like "addresses" : [ { "address" : ObjectId("55da4c4ee4b0754927018eb7"), "status" : false }, { "address" : ObjectId("55da4c4ee4b0754927018ec0"), "status" : false }, { "address" : ObjectId("55e86b74e4b05bc647b67490"), "status" : false } ]

Comment: Okay, what we want to achieve with it exactly? What is not working in it?

Comment: actually i am modifying the status field of address in addresses list , so i want the old status in addresses list , to log what was the old status and new status

Comment: Well your question does not seems to seeking for this address change  problem :-) But I've updated the answer. Please check it out.

Comment: thanxx again shashank, but i m now left with this single strange thing, it is showing the address but using the same approach , i m trying to get skills property but it is not in even $changedProperties list , also i have this relation along with many,  static belongsTo = [Skill], and in my db , the field is like "skills_$$manyToManyIds" : [
  ObjectId("557715c9e4b09a5fdbb658f2"),
  ObjectId("557715c9e4b09a5fdbb658f2"),
  ObjectId("55429736e4b0cad96d58c4cf")
 ],

Comment: and by the way , you got it right, its more than just address seeking problem :)

Comment: I think the `belongsTo` relationship needs to be on the `Skills` domain instead on `Employee`

Comment: i have certain scenario thats why i need it, can u suggest anything for this case

Comment: Hey shashank, one thing i got to know , that $changedProperties does not list the domain having id , and this was the reason skill was not listed in $changedProperties. My address domain was not having id , but as soon as i added one , now it's also not listed in $changedPropeties. Help

Comment: Oh! that's weird. Probably an issue for GORM for MongoDB. Thanks for the update.